# How do I bind a keyboard key to a label

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am trying to bind a keyboard button (preferably "ESC") to stop the code that is running inside the method. But the thing is, it only works with actual buttons, is there anyway to bypass this so it works when pressing labels aswell?

```
        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Control && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "ESC")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This does now work");
            }
}
```

[image: Error]

I've read somewhere that it is possible its just that the Visual Studio GUi doesnt provide it, but you can do it with code somehow, is this true?

Comment: did you try to make label focusable?

Comment: that's the wrong event handler. try the keydown event handler instead.

Comment: I think the problem is that label does not take focus, so keydown cant go to it... but if it does not, than the focus is on another element, so did you check which control take focus?

Comment: Do we have `click` event for asp.net label??

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to archieve. Do you want that pressing "ESC" , the excution of your code stops and the visual studio debbugger takes control?

Comment: @Bikee yes we do have a click event for asp.net label,  and Pikoh, I want the program to stop doing what its doing and go into a idle mode whcih I can add later, what I need to know is how to press a label with a key on my keyboard like (ESC) as a shortkey

Comment: I don't understand how you can press a label with a key. Either you click on it, or you can get the keypress in the form, not in the label. Label has no key events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. The following will get the Escape key when it is pressed when the focus is in the form regardless of what control has the focus. Just add this to the form (the code of course).

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Escape))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This works");
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: Im trying to make the software stop running the code, lets say im running the software and its typing something I want to be able to press ESC and make it stop typing.

Comment: I provided sample code that solves the problem that corresponds to the code you provided. You did not provide additional information about your application specifying what more needs to be done.